# How to reshape dataframe to get a subtraction of two segments for a given day and bucket?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks has a breakdown by date-bucket-group (i.e. for each day, we have many buckets and within those buckets we have two groups) and looks like this:

```
date       | bucket |  Group  |purchase
2020-01-01 | 1      |  A      | 12
2020-01-01 | 1      |  B      | 11

2020-01-01 | 2      |  A      | 14
2020-01-01 | 2      |  B      | 14

2020-02-01 | 1      |  A      | 11
2020-02-01 | 1      |  B      | 10
```

I would like to create a new dataframe, with a "difference" column that looks like this:

```
date       | bucket |  purchase | difference
2020-01-01 | 1      |  12-11=1 (Group A - Group B for that day/bucket)
2020-01-01 | 2      |  0
2020-02-01 | 1      |  1
```

How can I shape my df in such way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.assign(difference=dd.purchase.diff(-1)).iloc[0]

df1.groupby(["date",'bucket'],as_index=False).apply(function1).drop("purchase",axis=1)
```

out

```
    date    bucket  Group   difference
0   2020-01-01  1   A   1.0
1   2020-01-01  2   A   0.0
2   2020-02-01  1   A   1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape your dataframe before compute the diff:

```
out = (df.set_index(['date', 'bucket', 'group'])['purchase']
         .unstack('group').diff(-1, axis=1)['A']
         .rename('difference').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
         date  bucket  difference
0  2020-01-01       1           1
1  2020-01-01       2           0
2  2020-02-01       1           1
```

Or with `pivot`:

```
out = (df.pivot(['date', 'bucket'], 'group', 'purchase')
         .diff(-1, axis=1)['A'].rename('difference').reset_index())
```

Comment: Nice but note that this relies on the sorted order of the group. This would make things more difficult with more groups or an arbitrary sorting order, and less efficient in case of a large number of groups ;)

Comment: In this case, I think we can use `category` as dtype of `group` column to sort groups correctly?

Answer (score 2):

These methods doesn't rely on the values of the Group column, just that there are two ordered groups.

```
out = (df.set_index(['date', 'bucket', 'Group'])['purchase']
         .groupby(['date', 'bucket'])
         .diff(-1)
         .dropna()
         .droplevel(-1)
         .reset_index(name='difference'))
print(out)

# OR 

out = (df.groupby(['date', 'bucket'])
         .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('Group')['purchase']
                           .sum()
                           .diff(-1)
                           .dropna()))
out.columns = ['difference']
out = out.reset_index()
print(out)
```

Output:

```
          date  bucket  difference
0  2020-01-01        1         1.0
1  2020-01-01        2         0.0
2  2020-02-01        1         1.0
```

---

1-liner of mozway's:

```
(df.set_index(['date', 'bucket', 'Group'])['purchase']
   .agg(lambda x: x.xs('A', level='Group').sub(x.xs('B', level='Group')))
   .reset_index(name='difference'))
```

Output:

```
         date  bucket  difference
0  2020-01-01       1           1
1  2020-01-01       2           0
2  2020-02-01       1           1
```

Answer (score 2):

When needing to select and align, it's often easier to set the columns as index. Here using `xs` to select the groups:

```
s = df.set_index(['date', 'bucket', 'Group'])['purchase'].rename('difference')

(s.xs('A', level='Group')-s.xs('B', level='Group')).reset_index()
```

Variant using a DataFrame as intermediate, then renaming (useful to handle multiple columns):

```
df2 = df.set_index(['date', 'bucket', 'Group'])

(df2.xs('A', level='Group')-df2.xs('B', level='Group')
 ).reset_index().rename(columns={'purchase': 'difference'})
```

Output:

```
         date  bucket  difference
0  2020-01-01       1           1
1  2020-01-01       2           0
2  2020-02-01       1           1
```

Comment: I 1-lined your answer, feel free to steal it if you like it and I'll cut it back off my answer~ [Or tell me why doing it that way isn't as good :')]

Comment: @BeRT2me it's good ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use <code>DataFrame.pivot_table</code> with <code>DataFrame.sub</code>:
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['date','bucket'], columns='purchase', 
values='value')
   .sub(df1['B'], axis=0)
   .rename(columns={'A':'difference'})
   .reset_index()
print (df1)
  purchase       date  bucket  difference
  0 2020-01-01 2020-01-01       1           1
  1 2020-02-01 2020-02-01       1           1
```